# Как подсвечивать часть текста? [Легкий]

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть у меня пару функций, которые возвращают две строки

"Какие произведения писателей заставляются задуматься о великом?" --- Исходная строка
"Какие произведение писателей заставляются о великом?" ---- Строка, которую вернула функция

Мне надо, чтобы в исходной строке подсвечивалось так

**Какие произведения писателей заставляются** задуматься **о великом**

Прошу помощи

#### UPD (дополнил):

javascript

```
var string1 = "Какие произведения писателей заставляются задуматься о великом?";
var string2 = "Какие произведение писателей заставляются о великом?";

var elem = document.querySelector("result");
```

html:

```
<p class="result"></p> <! -- Просто пустой абзац -->
```

### UPD

Исходная строка может быть больше той, которая вернула функция, а может и не быть больше (ну вы поняли)

Comment: ©Есть у меня пару функций - а у меня нет

Comment: Хорошо, пусть будет

var string1 = "Какие произведения писателей заставляются задуматься о великом?";
var string2 = "Какие произведение писателей заставляются о великом?"

Comment: Приведите ваш код, даже не рабочий.

Comment: нужно разбить каждую строку на слова (это уже не так просто), потом идти по двум спискам слов, и если слова одинаковые, оборачивать слово в html-элемент со специальным классом. А если разные, пропускать слово в исходной строке. Для этого класса сделать подчеркивание в стилях. Все.

Comment: Исходная строка всегда больше той, что возвращается из функции? Или может быть наоборот?

Comment: @СвободуСергеюСуровцеву

Comment: @MikhailIonkin
Вставил код
Может быть, что исходная строка больше , а может быть и нет

Comment: если 2я строка может быть больше, то порядок обхода заметно усложнится. Опишите побробней правило, по которому определяется, какие слова должны выделяться

Comment: и привидите эту функцию, если возможно

Comment: @MikhailIonkin

"Комментарии используются для уточнения или указания на проблемы в сообщении. Устаревшие комментарии могут быть удалены" --- исходная строка
"Комментарии используются для уточнения сообщении. Устаревшие комментарии могут быть удалены" --- возвращаемая строка

Строка берётся из JSon'a -- никакой магии в этом нету

Comment: Если надо, то могу в скайпе описать и показать даже

Comment: ещё не помешает уточнить, это задачка? если да - то решение одно, если боевой код - другое

Comment: @qwabra Это задача, однако будет проверяться как боевой код(такой уж препод)

Comment: о, ок. просто для боевого можно нагуглить например вот это https://www.npmjs.com/package/diff `JsDiff.diffLines`

Comment: @qwabra Мне надо с помощью нативного Javascript'a как-то это сделать

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let string1 = "Какие произведения писателей заставляются задуматься о великом?";
let string2 = "Какие произведения писателей заставляются о великом?";

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = textHighlight(string1, string2);

function textHighlight(str1, str2) {
  str1 = str1.split(" ");

  let str = str1.map(subStr => {
    if (str2.includes(subStr)) {
      return `<span class="highlight">${subStr}</span>`;
    } else {
      return subStr;
    }
  });
  return str.join(" ");
}
```

```css
.highlight {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p id="result"></p>
```

Comment: str1.split is not a function --- ошибку сыпет

Comment: Извините, забыл указать, что у меня возвращается объект, а там есть свойство .text

Comment: ну так укажите это свойство в аргумент функции

Comment: Ошибку выдает в строчке if (str2.includes(subStr)) {

Comment: я чет не догоняю)

Comment: Работает с методом text
С методом textContent не работает

Answer (score 2):

немного не в тему, но.
что-то вроде `diff` строк с применением `Map`

```js
// --
const makeBold = (str) => `<b>${str}</b>`;
// разделить строку на массив слов
const split = (str) => str.split(' ');
// создать Map<string, boolean> из массива строк 
const toMap = (arr) => new Map(Array.from(arr, str => [str, true]));
// --
const compare = (a, b) => {
    let aM = toMap(split(a));
    let bM = toMap(split(b));
    // --
    aM.forEach((val, key) => { bM.has(key) && bM.set(key, false); });
    bM.forEach((val, key) => { aM.has(key) && aM.set(key, false); });
    // --
    return [
        Array.from(aM, ([key, val]) => val ? makeBold(key) : key).join(' '),
        Array.from(bM, ([key, val]) => val ? makeBold(key) : key).join(' '),
    ];
};
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', compare('Какие произведения писателей заставляют задуматься о великом', 'Какие произведения писателей заставляют о великом').join('<br>'));
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', '<hr>');
document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', compare('Какие произведения писателей заставляют задуматься о великом', 'Какие произведения писател заставляют о великом').join('<br>'));
```

а [там](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?alwaysStrict=false#code/PTAEFpwKAYwewHYGcAuoC2BDA1gUwEJwA2AJqALygAUqATgFyh0CWCA5gJQUB8oABgB4ARtwAkAbzoBfAcBF8oIUIAEQQAwggdhBALCCBWEEDcIIA4QQEIggGRBQgQRBDywHwggLhBAwiChAvCCrQgHhBVZs-sBMIOd1XvWERUJgAHImY0ShoUBiZY1k4eeNoAOiRwyKoAclBsjkUwSCgUAE9Q3FAARyrQilAAWUxQgRZ2ABpQIThiXEwEbgBuQvMrLVUTRubWhI6unqI%20gdB9dTcPL28XC2sbUCDkNBQ4JrrozFo4trYAbQBdDkYas94EXAB3KdCqAEFLzFKqQAZrQ4OgqBdaJ06MkbnROrEAK64B4FJTFeCHUDwdChC6Vc6Ma6dIRE2acRhw8nQ8l3ZLiKCgJmgRZoTANerHU40TIoCEcArMlm4NBCDmULnNHkRPlCAWM5no6BC9nAuC0ACimBgAAsqFQAG6YIidPClLjkXjiLoNVI6zBIKhmrgAMhdNvSIqduFKnSBxqQuC4UkFzLFas12r1huNpp9FqtoFV9sdztAbqTtsDfLNfoDQdAIYVTKVxdAtBFiNoCFANzLQr%20tABwNB4PZnSoN1zoCNRAeyV7oAA-BgcARiCRvebQIxnakAFZwVg5PIcdr15mN5sgsFUMUdrs%20zq9-uWnvG4ejvCEUhTriz%20MLpcIFf5ddCu5QKRQH8kOAwRF0FwBAUFSboSEBVhA1oFAfhIedtWAlAAAkABUGgAGRyIRcCBdVcGAkhsk6HE8QrKgy2yQAsEFUGx9G0UBAH4QaxVm8bQdEcfRAHkQJj9DMCY9G0QBOEFAdQPEMVRvF0LjADkQQxRNUTQ7HcEwzB4qxQDYgwbCsVxiMomi6IY5irFY9jtE4njGL4gTdGEhSLEk6S5NADStP0HS9PXDgn2XbJhFobh8gKKA-wAoCQLAuAINSKDcBguCEJgJC0Mw7DcPwwjiLyAQdUC-Jf3-QCkKimK4oS%20DEJA1KsOyHC8IrLKSLBMjcAooVqNo%20imJY9Q2I47jeP4wxBJEsTHKk2T5LEpSVOMNTXM0vQPN0-SOsM7qTLMgarJskbdAciTJpctzls8-SfMXPyAqCgUgA) то же самое на TS

Comment: У вас получилось выделение "наоборот". И "слова" лучше разделять не по пробелу, а по `\s+`, но это заметно усложнит алгоритм, и `\s+` в большинстве случаев не нужно. Хотя способ интересный и понятный.

Answer (score 1):

**Последовательный** поиск от последнего совпадения - это и логичнее, и (должно быть) быстрее проверки каждого слова через `includes(word)`:

```js
const str1 = 'Какие произведения писателей заставляют задуматься о великом?';
const str2 = 'Какие произведение писателей заставляют о великом?';
const elem = document.querySelector('.result'); 
elem.innerHTML = wrapMatches(str1, str2, '<span class="green">'); 
console.log(elem.innerHTML); 

function wrapMatches(strA, strB, wrapper='<b>') {
  const [wordsA, wordsB] = [strA.split(/\s+/), strB.split(/\s+/)].sort(
    (a, b) => b.length - a.length
  ); 
  const [wordsAlc, wordsBlc] = [wordsA, wordsB].map(
    arr => arr.map(itm => itm.toLowerCase())
  ); 
  const endTag = `</${wrapper.match(/^<([^\s>]+)/)[1]}>`, 
        len = wordsA.length, 
        result = []; 
  let open = false; 
  for (let lastMatchIdx = 0, i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
    let matchIdx = wordsBlc.indexOf(wordsAlc[i], lastMatchIdx); 
    if (matchIdx !== -1) {
      if (!open)
        open = !!result.push(wrapper);   // всегда вернет true: ="NOT(NOT(n)), n > 0"
      lastMatchIdx = matchIdx; 
    } else if (open) {
      open = !result.push(endTag);       // всегда вернет false: ="NOT(n), n > 0"
    }
    result.push(wordsA[i]); 
  }
  if (open)
    result.push(endTag);
  return result.join(' '); 
}
```

```css
p { font-family: sans-serif; }
.green { font-weight: bold; color: #4d4; }
```

```html
<p class="result"></p>
```

Второй аргумент `indexOf` это начальный индекс поиска - передаем индекс последнего найденного слова (`lastMatchIdx`), и получаем короткий проход по массиву: даже в пессимистичном сценарии, будет проверено `length - lastMatchIdx` элементов (только часть массива, а не всегда *все* его элементы от начала до конца).
Плюс, `indexOf` с массивами сам по себе работает быстрее `includes`.

Плюс, сохраняется последовательность, поэтому не будет неожиданных результатов при строках вида `'aaa bbb ccc bbb', 'aaa ccc bbb'`.

Comment: а зачем `toLowerCase`? А вообще, код выглядит сложным. Хотя и задача непонятная и не такая простая, как может показаться.

Comment: @MikhailIonkin, Для того чтобы сравнение слов было регистронезависимым.